# Adaptive payment integration in PayPal Pro

Tags: paypal

We are using PayPal pro in our application. Now, we want to use adaptive payments in our application.

Ex. if a user buy a product of $100 from our application then $97.00 will be given to my vendor and $3.00 will be given to my account.

We try to find out the solution for this but can't find any info.

Comment: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/ have you looked into this?

Comment: Hello  techycommerce, Yes we check this but this is not for PayPal pro

Answer (score 0):

[Adaptive Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/) is a feature which is compatible with a PayPal Business/Premier Accounts. The same is supported in PayPal Payments PRO too.
You will just need to login to paypal-apps.com->Create an application->You will get APP ID upon approval that you can use in your Adaptive Payment API calls.